# How to get Windows 10 send to compress all folders that start with a period/dot?

Tags: windows, windows-10, compression, zip

I saw a similar question for Windows 7 but my question is for Windows 10.

In Windows 10, if you right click on a folder and use Send To > Compress, the ZIP file will not include all of the folders that start with a dot/period.

I created a folder like this:

```
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST IN\.bravo
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST IN\.bravo\one.txt
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST IN\.charlie
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST IN\.charlie\one.txt
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST IN\alpha
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST IN\alpha\one.txt
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST IN\one.txt
```

I used Send To > Compress to ZIP the `TEST IN` folder and then extracted to `TEST OUT`:

```
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST OUT\TEST IN
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST OUT\TEST IN\.bravo
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST OUT\TEST IN\.bravo\one.txt
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST OUT\TEST IN\alpha
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST OUT\TEST IN\alpha\one.txt
C:\Users\myUserID\Downloads\TEST OUT\TEST IN\one.txt
```

The `.charlie` folder is not there.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you display the contents of the original zip file your created?

Comment: I suggest that you don't use the built-in compression utilities.  They are weak at best and don't have many avenues for configuration.  I suggest you try 7zip or similar to do this.

Comment: can 7zip work with sendto?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas It's the same as what it extracted. The `.charlie` folder is not there.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I am now. But I wonder how many folks are using the built in compress, expecting/assuming it got everything. They'll be in for a rude awakening much later when they go to extract and the folders/files aren't there.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas No but it adds its own right click context menu.

Comment: I'm going to see if I can emulate this issue - What if there are dummy files (not zero bytes) in the .charlie folder? Does it still not appear after extracting?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Correct, dummy/empty files. Correct, it does not appear after extracting. I identified this issue when I tried to compress a project folder that had a `.vscode` folder in it. Just create a temp folder, create some folders `.folders` and try to compress the root folder.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Were you able to?

Comment: No - Need the windows 10 version - Mine worked fine

Comment: after extraction, can you type ATTRIB on the command line - I'm wondering if the folders are hidden for some odd reason

Comment: @JohnnyVegas You see the files after extraction? I don't. Not even hidden.